# Window function with PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a PySpark Dataframe and my goal is to create a `Flag` column whose value depends on the value of the `Amount` column.
Basically, **for each Group**, I want to know if **in any of the first three months**, there is an **amount greater than 0** and if that is the case, the value of the Flag column will be 1 for all the group, otherwise the value will be 0.

I will include an example to clarify a bit better.

Initial PySpark Dataframe:

| Group | Month | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 2 | 0 |
| A | 3 | 35 |
| A | 4 | 0 |
| A | 5 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0 |
| C | 2 | 0 |
| C | 3 | 0 |
| C | 4 | 13 |
| D | 1 | 0 |
| D | 2 | 24 |
| D | 3 | 0 |

Final PySpark Dataframe:

| Group | Month | Amount | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 35 | 1 |
| A | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 5 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 4 | 13 | 0 |
| D | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| D | 2 | 24 | 1 |
| D | 3 | 0 | 1 |

Basically, what I want is for each group, to sum the amount of the first 3 months. If that sum is greater than 0, the flag is 1 for all the elements of the group, and otherwise is 0.

Comment: are the first 3 months always 1,2,3?

Comment: Yes, they are always 1,2,3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `flag` column by applying a `Window` function. Create a psuedo-column which becomes 1 if the criteria is met and then finally sum over the psuedo-column and if it's greater than 0, then there was atleast once row that met the criteria and set the `flag` to 1.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

data = [("A", 1, 0, ), 
("A", 2, 0, ), 
("A", 3, 35, ), 
("A", 4, 0, ), 
("A", 5, 0, ), 
("B", 1, 0, ), 
("B", 2, 0, ), 
("C", 1, 0, ), 
("C", 2, 0, ), 
("C", 3, 0, ), 
("C", 4, 13, ), 
("D", 1, 0, ), 
("D", 2, 24, ), 
("D", 3, 0, ), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Group", "Month", "Amount", ))

ws = W.partitionBy("Group").orderBy("Month").rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.unboundedFollowing)

criteria = F.when((F.col("Month") < 4) & (F.col("Amount") > 0), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))

(df.withColumn("flag", F.when(F.sum(criteria).over(ws) > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)))
).show()

"""
+-----+-----+------+----+
|Group|Month|Amount|flag|
+-----+-----+------+----+
|    A|    1|     0|   1|
|    A|    2|     0|   1|
|    A|    3|    35|   1|
|    A|    4|     0|   1|
|    A|    5|     0|   1|
|    B|    1|     0|   0|
|    B|    2|     0|   0|
|    C|    1|     0|   0|
|    C|    2|     0|   0|
|    C|    3|     0|   0|
|    C|    4|    13|   0|
|    D|    1|     0|   1|
|    D|    2|    24|   1|
|    D|    3|     0|   1|
+-----+-----+------+----+
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Window function with `count` and `when`.

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('Group')
df = df.withColumn('Flag', F.count(
        F.when((F.col('Month') < 4) & (F.col('Amount') > 0), True)).over(w))
     .withColumn('Flag', F.when(F.col('Flag') > 0, 1).otherwise(0))
```